# How to implement an arraylist from a superclass in the constructor of a subclass?

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, subclass, superclass

I'm currently trying to learn Java and I encountered a problem on which I'm a little stuck.

I have one superclass and two subclasses that extend it, in  the superclass I created an Arraylist that I want to use in the constructor of the subclasses but I'm not quite sure about my solution.

I would be glad for any help and please let me know if you need any further information in order to understand my question.

So here is what I've tried:

```
public class Superclass{ 
    private String something;
    private ArrayList<String> list;

    public Superclass(String something){ 
      this.something = something; 
      list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    }
}


public class Subclass extends Superclass{ 

     public String someelse; 

     public Subclass(String name, ArrayList<String> list, String 
                   someelse){ 
          super(name); 
          this.someelse = someelse; 
          list = new ArrayList<String> 
     }
}
```

It doesn't through out any errors but is it the right way to do it like that, or is there a way to have the ArrayList in the super brackets? 
I want to initilize it the superclass, add elements in the subclasses and use it in a different class.

Comment: if you want to access the list in the subclass, it must be declared non `private` (so either `protected` or `public` or package default) and then you need to initialize it only in the super

Comment: This code is not valid Java code. So it can't possibly compile. So no, it's not the correct way to do what you want to do (whatever that might be).

Comment: Why do you want to assign an empty ArrayList to `list` in the subclass ctor, if you have already done this in the superclass ctor?

Comment: So you're saying that I can set it to protected in the superclass and then only initialize it there, rather than initializing it twice in both?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, I did not fully understand the question. I would recommend having the list in `Superclass` as protected, which allows your `Subclass` to access it discretely, without public access. See below:

```java
public class Superclass {

    private String name;
    protected List<String> list;

    public Superclass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

public class Subclass  {

    public String someName;

    public Subclass(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.someName = name;
    }

    public void add(String string) {
        list.add(string); <- because of the list being protected, this refers to the list in the super class
    }
}
```

My advice though would be to leave the adding and removing of elements to the `Superclass`, unless you are planning on having any extra checks in the `Subclass` when adding/removing elements from the list. This would mean moving the `add` method to the `Superclass` as such:

```java
public class Superclass {

    private String name;
    protected List<String> list;

    public Superclass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(String string) {
        list.add(string);
    }
}

public class Subclass  {

    public String someName;

    public Subclass(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.someName = name;
    }
}
```

You would then create and use it as such (works for both examples above):

```java
Subclass subclass = new Subclass("sub1");
subclass.add("string1"); <- gets added to superclass list
```

For more info on scope identifiers, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in).

Comment: Why like so? What does this do? What did you change? Why did you change it? A good answer contains explanation, it doesn't simply dump code.